# Mapping list of lists to pandas Series

Tags: python, list, dictionary

New to Python. Easy question that's making my head spin.

Let's say I have a pandas Series as follows:

```
my_series = pd.Series([(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)])
```

I also have a "lookup" lists of lists, as follows:

```
my_lookup = [([0,1], 0), ([1,1], 1), ([1,2], 2), ([2,2], 3), ([0,3], 4), ([1,3], 5), ([2,3], 6)]
```

1) I'd like to know how to replace each pair in my_series with it's corresponding value in my_lookup. In this case, my_series should become pd.Series([2, 6, 5]).

2) I'd like to know how to create a new Series with corresponding values, instead of replacing as in the previous question.

3) Do the answers change if not every "key" is in my_lookup? For example, if my_lookup instead read:

```
my_lookup = [([0,1], 0), ([1,1], 1), ([2,2], 3), ([0,3], 4), ([1,3], 5), ([2,3], 6)]
```

Edit: I thought to use a dictionary and the map function like so:

```
df["Gender"] = df["Sex"].map({"female":0, "male":1}).astype(int)
```

..But my keys are lists, and Python seems to not like that, so I'm trying a different route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track with using a dictionary.

Is it possible that your 'keys' will change?  From the initial declaration of your series, it looks like they will not, but you do have them as lists in `my_lookup`.

If they keys won't change, you can convert them to tuples and use them as keys in a dictionary.  For example (in normal python, as I don't have pandas installed on this computer to test):

```
d = {tuple(k): v for k,v in my_lookup}
```

Then, to replace each key in the series, you could do something like:

```
fReplace = lambda k: d[k]
new_series = map(fReplace, my_series) # or my_series.map if you're in pandas

# alternatively (and there's probably a nicer way, I don't have pandas to play with)
new_series = pd.Series(map(fReplace, my_series))
```

If not every key is in the lookup, you need to decide whether there's a sensible default value.  If there is, you can use `.get` on your dictionary:

```
fReplace = lambda k: d.get(k, sensible_default_value)
```

If not, you could use, say, `None` as your default and then filter to resulting series to remove values of `None`.